# Multiple instruction constraints anchor

Tags: anchor

If I want to use instruction data in my account constraints, I can do it like so:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(my_param: u32)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [my_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
}
```

Let's say I want to use multiple params. Intuitively, I tried the below:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(my_param: u32)]
#[instruction(my_second_param: u32)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [my_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref(), my_second_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
}
```

This gives me the error `cannot find value "my_second_param" in this scope`. Is there a way to achieve this out of the box (which isn't merging my two params into a struct)? Or does anchor only allow one instruction constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I'm just an idiot :)

The way to do this is simply writing all the instruction vars inside the constraint:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(my_param: u32, my_second_param: u32)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [my_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref(), my_second_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
}
```